# angular2 correct way to have service call member function of Component

Tags: typescript, angular

How should I let a service call method of a component (i am using typescript with Angular2)?

My service need to occasionally notify components some events. (update them randomly over time)

One way I could think of is to let the service keep a ref to the component and call component's method directly using the ref.

Is there other better/proper way to do it in Angular2?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provide an observable the component can subscribe to:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  Subject someEvent = new Subject();
  doSomething() {
    this.someEvent.next('someValue');
  }
}
```

```
@Component({ ...})
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(myService:MyService) {
    myService.someEvent.subscribe(value => this.someMethod(value));
  }

  someMethod(value) {
    console.log(value);
  }
}
```